# svn checkout fails with "E160006: No such revision" after relocation and upgrade

Tags: svn, version-control

I have an SVN repository that just recently started complaining on checkouts of a particular folder that the checkout fails due to "E160006: No such revision XXX", where XXX is the number of a particular revision.  The missing revision appears to date from 6 years ago.  Checkout of other folders works fine.  I am not sure what caused this, but several weeks ago I switched to using a backup of my original repository that I had been maintaining using svnsync.  I also recently updated my (ubuntu linux) operating system, which lead subversion to request that I execute "svn upgrade" on my working copy, which I attempted, but I had to stop the upgrade because of a missing VPN connection, which lead to a completely non-functional working copy (but I don't see how problems with a working copy could be related to this problem with checkout; more likely the problem is in the other direction).

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem (for example, to recover the missing revisions or just instruct subversion to ignore them)?  I have the original repository that the "svnsync repo" was generated from, but this original repository lacks recent commits.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution to this problem myself.  Because I had the original, uncorrupted repository around, I created a new clone of that using:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/newclone
svnsync initialize file:///path/to/newclone https://url/to/orginalrepo
svnsync sync file:///path/to/newclone
```

Then I instructed that new clone to sync to the old (corrupted) clone of the original repo:

```
svnsync initialize --allow-non-empty file:///path/to/newclone file:///path/to/oldclone
```

The `--allow-non-empty` option allowed me to sync recent revisions in oldclone, without worrying about the fact that there are revisions in newclone that are absent from oldclone:

```
svnsync sync file:///path/to/newclone
```

This produced a working repository with all the revisions from both originalrepo and oldclone.